# Day difference in the java script function

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example.

Day start from :: `9/3/15 14:00:00`

Day End to :: `10/3/15 13:59:59`

Consider day is end at 14.00.00 not from 24.00.00

```
Example 1 ::
Input
Start date :: 9/3/15 15:05:00
End date :: 10/3/15 7:05:00
```

Here, day is start after 14.00.00 and end before the 14.00.00 at the next day so here not complete the day.
So it will return 0 days

```
Example 2 ::
Input
Start date :: 10/3/15 12:05:00
End date :: 10/3/15 15:05:00
```

Here, day is start before 14.00.00 and end after the 14.00.00 at the next day so here complete the day.
So it will return 1 days

Here, day is end at the 14.00.00

Comment: please elaborate this more

Comment: What is the question and where is the relevant code?

Comment: check the question gain i edited that, here is no code for that because i can't get any logic for that.. any thing else..?

Comment: When you say "it will return 1 days", what will return 1 days?  There must be some code somewhere doing a computation, right?

Comment: need this type of function. which return 1 day. are you understated this question..?

Comment: still - what is the question here? You want to know how to code that behaviour you posted? Or you want to avoid that and AWLAYS return that its a day difference if the Date-Day is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function dayDiff(sdate, edate) {
                var df1 = (Math.abs(sdate.getDay() - edate.getDay()));
                var timeDiff = Math.abs(sdate.getTime() - edate.getTime());
                var df = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
                if (sdate.getDay() == edate.getDay()) {
                    if (sdate.getHours() < 14 && sdate.getMinutes() <= 59 && sdate.getSeconds() <= 59 && edate.getHours() >= 14 && edate.getMinutes() >= 0 && edate.getSeconds() >= 0)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return 0;
                } else if (df1 == 1) {
                    if (sdate.getHours() < 14 && sdate.getMinutes() <= 59 && sdate.getSeconds() <= 59 && edate.getHours() >= 14 && edate.getMinutes() >= 0 && edate.getSeconds() >= 0)
                        return 1;
                    else
                        return 0;
                } else if (df1 > 1) {
                    if (sdate.getHours() < 14 && sdate.getMinutes() <= 59 && sdate.getSeconds() <= 59 && edate.getHours() >= 14 && edate.getMinutes() >= 0 && edate.getSeconds() >= 0)
                        return df + 1;
                    else
                        return df;
                }
            }
```

This function code requirement is to get 2 date difference start date and end date.
But day start from 14 hour (2PM).

```
for example ::
1
    start date : 13/03/2015 15:10:55
    End date : 14/03/2015 10:15:45
    day difference return 0

 2  start date : 13/03/2015 15:10:55
    End date : 14/03/2015 14:15:45
    day difference return 1

3   start date : 14/03/2015 10:09:55
    End date : 14/03/2015 14:15:45
    day difference return 1
```

Comment: This function code requirement is to get 2 date difference start date and end date.
But day start from 14 hour (2PM).
for example start date : 13/03/2015 15:10:55

Answer (score 1):

```
function dayDiff(sdate, edate) {                
                var df = (Math.abs(sdate.getDay() - edate.getDay()));                                
                if (sdate.getHours() < 14 && sdate.getMinutes() <= 59 && sdate.getSeconds() <= 59 && edate.getHours() > 14 && edate.getMinutes() > 0 && edate.getSeconds() > 0) {
                    df+=1;                 
                }
                return df;
            }
```

Comment: you should also add some description and/or reference links along with code

Comment: While this may help, you should explain the code so that it provides insight to future viewers of a question. Simply pasting code isn't really considered a great answer.